# Dynamic SQL Set Golang

Tags: sqlite, go

I have a doubt about the structure of a SQLite query. I'm trying to update a user-selected value in the table referencing the row by the username.
The table is called `Data` and has these columns: `USERNAME,PASSWORD,ADDRESS,NOTES`.

I'm using SQL drivers for GO (`_ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"`), here's my query:

```
...
stmt, err := db.Prepare("UPDATE Data SET ?=? WHERE USERNAME=?")
check(err)
res, err := stmt.Exec(splittedQuery[0], splittedQuery[1],splittedQuery[2])
...
```

From this sequence I can only get a syntax error: `near "?": syntax error`.
How should I manage this? If it's a trivial question I'm sorry, I'm just new to GO and trying to learn something out of it.

Thanks

Comment: You can not use placeholder for column names.

Comment: Those aren't placeholders. They're parameters similar to Go function arguments. The values never become part of the query. The server compiles the query into an execution plan and then executes it with the supplied parameter values. Next time the same query is encountered, the server uses the existing execution plan with the new parameter values

Comment: It's for that reason that object names (tables, columns, functions etc) can't be passed as parameters. It's like asking to pass function *names* to Go functions and somehow end up calling the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that in SQL. It's not specific to sqlite either. Parameterized placeholder are only for value, you cannot change the structure of the query with that. Here are some documentation links for your reference:

- https://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/#bindvars
- https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/bind-parameters

What you are trying to do is building a dynamic query. You can do that by building your query string yourself:

```golang
query := "UPDATE Data SET " + col_name + "=? WHERE USERNAME=?"
```

But depending from the source of your data for the column_name you need to be cautious of sql injection (this is a whole other topic, for fun you can look at that https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png).

There are also a few library available to help you with that. For example to name one, you can check this one https://github.com/Masterminds/squirrel

Comment: These aren't placeholders, they're parameters, similar to function arguments in Go.  You can't pass table and column names for the same reason you can't pass type and variable names in Go. The value never becomes part of the query. The server compiles the query into an execution plan and *then* executes it with the supplied parameter values.